# Rails - RFC 5322 error report from Sendgrid to Outlook/Hotmail/Microsoft emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, sendgrid

I seem to be receiving bounces for emails going to hotmail, outlook and microsoft addresses.

I am sending using sendgrid SMTP via Ruby on rails. My hosting environment is Heroku.

Would anybody be able to substantiate why this might occur? Ideally, I would like to implement a fix without installing a gem.

Please let me know if you require further details.

Comment: A little code would be nice :)

Comment: Sorry - issue has been solved. I was being a donkey and didn't provide a correct from email address.